# Trying to edit HDRP shader emission intensity during runtime

Tags: unity-game-engine

I am trying to set the emission intensity of an hdr material during runtime.

At first I tried:

```
self.material.SetFloat("_EmissiveIntensity", 1f);
```

But this didn't seem to work, probably because I'm using Universal Render Pipeline.

I then tried a bunch of suggestions from unity forums such as [this one](https://forum.unity.com/threads/unity-5-standard-or-standard-specular-change-emission-of-material-at-run-time.320557/) and [this one](https://forum.unity.com/threads/adjusting-emission-intensity-of-a-material-with-the-hdrp-lit-shader-at-runtime-not-working.748229/) and also [this one](https://forum.unity.com/threads/hdr...d-lead-to-black-material.732350/#post-6820094).
However, none of these seemed to work.

This is what is shown in the editor during runtime [image]

But my code should change the intensity to 1.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Can you show your shader? What exactly does `didn't seem to work` mean? Did it work or not? Getting any errors?

Comment: I am not getting any errors. The intensity just isn't changing.

Comment: The emissions intensity is not the se as the HDR color intensity though

Comment: Ok. Do you know how I could change that?

Comment: Ok. That makes sense. Do you know if there is such a way to multiply it to be sure that the end intensity is a 1? When I tried your code, the end intensity wasn't exactly 1.

Comment: I recommend [this blog](https://forum.unity.com/threads/how-to-change-hdr-colors-intensity-via-shader.531861/#post-3501287) at the bottom there is a good explanation why it will never end up with exact values

Answer (score 0):

The `_EmmisionIntensity` as far as I know is not the se as the HDR color intensity.

HDR colors are basically a vector which is the result of

```
yourColor * 2f ^ exposure
```

So what you could do (not knowing the exact keyword for the emission color) is probably something like

```
self.material.SetVector("_EmmissionColor", ((Vector4) yourColor) * Mathf.Exp(2f, exposure));
```

Comment: I've tried what you've suggested, but it ends up with the intensity being equal to about 7 for some reason. I tried dividing everything by seven, but that didn't seem to work either.

Answer (score 0):

Unity has guidance on this. In short, you can't change that property at runtime. Instead, use a different property: https://docs.unity3d.com/Packages/com.unity.render-pipelines.high-definition@12.0/manual/adjusting-emissive-intensity-at-runtime.html

> For High Definition Render Pipeline (HDRP) non-Shader Graph shaders, such as the Lit, Unlit, and Decal shaders, changing the _EmissiveIntensity property does not have any effect at runtime. This is because _EmissiveIntensity is not an independent property. The shader only uses _EmissiveIntensity to serialize the property in the UI and stores the final result in the _EmissiveColor property. To edit the intensity of emissive materials, set the _EmissiveColor and multiply it by the intensity you want.